# Merge differencing and parent vhd into new vhd

Tags: vhd, diskpart

Using DISKPART and the "VDISK MERGE" option, is it possible to specify that you want to keep the existing child/parent disks and do a merge into a new vhd file? That is; I still want to keep my original child/parent disks. As far as I can tell from the resources I've found, the only option is to select a differencing vdisk and merge it with it's parent(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a copy of the parent and child first, do the merge, and then rename the copies back.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing too. Find it a bit strange that there's no option for specifying an 'output file' in the VDISK MERGE command though.

Comment: If you want to duplicate a disk image, which is essentially what you're suggesting, you don't want to merge, you want to mirror.  Mount the child VHD, create a mirror and then break it once it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

Cant find any other useful information on that sorry, my suggestion: boot the machine with with some WinPE or Dos from cd/floppy and use norton ghost or altiris to clone the disk that the machine sees to an other VHD drive or file share location.

I guess linux and some "dd" magic will do to.